# Apple HealthKit - Do workouts have associated heart rate data?

Tags: ios, healthkit

I'm writing my own fitness app that I hope to bridge the void between the Fitbit app and Apple Health (I finally ditched my Blaze for an Apple Watch). So far I am able to retrieve the workouts for the last 7 days but I want to display a heart rate graph (like Fitbit does) for the workout when you click to view it.  Does the workout contain the heart rate samples recorded during the workout or do I need to query the heart rate for start and end time matching the workout separately? I've played about a bit and tried to find the answer in the documentation but I'm finding it a bit difficult to understand so sorry if I've missed something obvious!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Workout app on Apple Watch does not associate heart rate samples with its `HKWorkout` instances, so querying for heart rate samples using `+[HKQuery predicateForObjectsFromWorkout:]` will not return any results. Instead, you should query for heart rate samples using a date range predicate spanning the duration of the workout.

Comment: Hm, that's what I'd suspected, thanks for confirming @Allan. The way you specify the Workout app on Apple Watch makes me wonder... are workouts from 3rd party apps able to associate heart rate data?

Comment: How do we fetch the start and end date time of a workout ? After getting all the workout , we only get the duration of the workout.